# RASA: All Intents Showing 1.0 Confidence, Even with Random String Messages

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I've recently started working with RASA and I'm encountering challenges with intent confidence. Regardless of the input message, **even if it's a random string** like "3sdfhadhfoae 973 hdkjhsf d", **RASA** **consistently assigns a** **confidence score of 1.0 to the intent** 'zypher_connect' (In my case zypher_connect intent). I'm unsure why this is happening.

I've shared the relevant files here

nlu.yml

```
version: '3.1'

nlu:
  - intent: zypher_connect
    examples: |
      - hey
      - hello
      - hi
      - hello there
      - good morning
      - good evening

 - intent: connect_agent
    examples: |
      - could you please connect me to agent?
      - Can you transfer my call to an agent, please?
      - I'd like to speak with an agent. Could you connect me, please?
      - Is it possible to get in touch with an agent right now?
      - I need assistance from an agent. Can you connect me to one?
      - Could you transfer me to a customer service representative?

  - intent: flight_status
    examples: |
      - What's the status of my flight, [BA123](flight_no)?
      - Can you check if my flight, [LH456](flight_no), is delayed?
      - I'd like to know the status of flight [AF789](flight_no).
      - Is my flight, [QR321](flight_no), on time?
      - Can you provide the current status of flight [EK654](flight_no)?
      - Has flight [AA987](flight_no) landed yet?
```

rules.yml

```
version: '3.1'

rules:
  - rule: Ask the user to rephrase whenever they send a message with low NLU confidence
    steps:
    - intent: nlu_fallback
    - action: utter_please_rephrase
```

stories.yml

```
version: '3.1'

stories:
  - story: path about agent connect
    steps:
      - intent: connect_agent
      - action: action_agent

  - story: path about zypher connect
    steps:
      - intent: connect_zypher
      - action: action_zypher

  - story: path about flight status
    steps:
      - intent: flight_status
      - action: action_flight_status

  - story: handle fallback
    steps:
    - intent: nlu_fallback
    - action: action_default_fallback
```

domain.yml

```
version: '3.1'

intents:
  - connect_agent
  - connect_zypher
  - flight_status

actions:
  - action_agent
  - action_zypher
  - action_flight_status

session_config:
  session_expiration_time: 60
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true
```

Can someone explain why this is going on and offer some advice on how to fix it?